# Is there a software that can understand the webpage language?

Tags: software-distribution

Is there a software that can understand the webpage language? like if the most of the page is like

> JAXAでは、宇宙航空研究開発を応援して下さる皆様のお気持ちを広く受け入れるため、寄附金の募集を行っております。
>   集まりました寄附金は、寄附者様が選択した事業に確実に活用し、宇宙航空分野の研究開発で日本が世界に伍し、同時に貢献していくための源泉とさせていただきます。

this page is in japanese.....

i know google do it with it's dictionary but is there a developer-tool version from google or an API?

Comment: yes, look at https://developers.google.com/translate/

Comment: or bing translate api: http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis

Comment: @PeterRitchie it is not free or did i misunderstand?

Comment: Sometimes they're free up until a certain number of requests.  But, you didn't specify free-only options...

Comment: From the [help/on-topic] page: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.